# After using <InputSelect> first value in select is empty

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have been working for a while with Blazor Server host model and now i am building forum with it. I have small strange case, maybe someone will help me to find solution.

**This is EditForm**

```
<EditForm Model="@Category">
    <InputSelect id="category" class="form-select" @bind-Value="@Category.Id">
           
            @foreach (var category in Categories!)
                {
                    <option value="@category.Id">@category.Category</option>
                }
    </InputSelect>
</EditForm>
```

**This is list of items:**

```
Categories = await _repository!.GetAllCategories();
```

**This is how "GetAllCategories()" looks like:**

```
        public async Task<IEnumerable<CategoryEntity>> GetAllCategories()
    {
       return await _context.Categories.OrderBy(x=>x.Id).ToListAsync();
    }
```

and the thing is:

**First item in Select is blank:**
[image]

How can i make first item as Value of it? Has someone found something similar?

Comment: This is still an issue in Blazor and has been answered before here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65172633/first-option-in-blazor-inputselect-displayed-but-value-is-null.  In short, the current solution is to add an "empty" option as the first item with checks for null in your method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [First option in Blazor InputSelect displayed but value is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65172633/first-option-in-blazor-inputselect-displayed-but-value-is-null)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found solution.

I changed:

```
 <InputSelect id="category" class="form-select" @bind-Value="@Category.Id">
```

to:

```
 <InputSelect id="category" class="form-select" @bind-Value="@Category.Category">
```